# Remove seperator lines on Android Plot Pie Chart

Tags: android, charts, pie-chart, androidplot

I've used android plot pie chart to plot data in my application.  My problem is that the separator lines in the pie chart (in image attached below).  I can't seem to get rid of the black line no matter what way I have set up the chart.

Here is how I've set it up:

```
//Sets up the pie chart to display the user beer ratings figures visually
private void chartSetup(PieChart p){

    PieWidget pw = p.getPieWidget();

    pw.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

    SegmentFormatter sf1 = new SegmentFormatter();
    sf1.configure(getActivity(),R.xml.pie_segment_formatter1);

    sf1.getFillPaint();

    SegmentFormatter sf2 = new SegmentFormatter();

    sf2.configure(getActivity(), R.xml.pie_segment_formatter2);
    sf2.getFillPaint();

    Segment monthly = new Segment("", totalBeerCount);
    Segment total = new Segment("", monthlyBeerCount);

    p.setPlotMarginBottom(0);

    p.addSegment(monthly, sf1);
    p.addSegment(total, sf2);
    p.redraw();
    p.getBorderPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    p.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    p.getRenderer(PieRenderer.class).setDonutSize(.90f, PieRenderer.DonutMode.PERCENT);
}
```

and here are the two segment formatter xml files:

**pie_segment_formatter1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config
    fillPaint.color="@color/appRed"
    labelPaint.textSize="5dp"
    innerEdgePaint.color = "@color/appRed"
    outerEdgePaint.color = "@color/appRed"/>
```

**pie_segment_formatter2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config
    fillPaint.color="@color/lightGrey"
    labelPaint.textSize="5dp"
    innerEdgePaint.color = "@color/lightGrey"
    outerEdgePaint.color = "@color/lightGrey"/>
```

I have tried including `linePaint.strokeWidth="0dp"` in the config files but that doesn't make any difference.  If anyone could help me on this i'd greatly appreciate it.

[image: Pie Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the paint used to draw the radial edges.  Add this line to each of your formatter xml cfgs:

```
radialEdgePaint.color="#00000000"
```

Or programmatically within your Java src:

```
formatter.setRadialEdgePaint(null);
```

Comment: Excellent..easy when you know how! Thank you